# Resolution with media screen

Tags: css

I´m using the following in css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .details-container {width: 121%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
     .details-container {width: 201%;}
}
```

If i try a resolution under 400px, it takes the 640px css as reference, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A screen of 400px fits inside both your queries, that means it will get both values but the last one set will prevail per CSS cascading rules.

You can flip the order of the queries or specify a min-width in the second one

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .details-container {width: 121%;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 640px){
     .details-container {width: 201%;}
}
```

Comment: And how can i separate them?